# Populating combobox with two different objects

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, interface, combobox

I want to populate a combobox with two different objects using an interface. This is what I currently got. This works but now I would like to have a display member and value member for each object, how would I do so?

In Controller.cs

```
public List<IMusic> Populate()
        {
            List<IMusic> newList = new List<IMusic>();

            foreach(Track t in tr.GetAllTracks()){
                newList.Add(t);
            }

            foreach (Artist a in ar.GetAllArtists())
            {
                newList.Add(a);
            }
            return newList;
        }
```

IMusic.cs

```
  interface IMusic
    {

    }
```

The combobox with DataSource:

```
cBMainScreen_Search.DataSource = controller.Populate();
```

GetAllTracks() :

```
public List<Track> GetAllTracks()
        {
            return db.Track.ToList();
        }
```

GetAllArtists() :

```
 public List<Artist> GetAllArtists()
        {
            return db.Artist.ToList();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just setup some properties in your interface:

```
interface IMusic
{
    string Display { get; set; }
    string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your Track class (which should implement IMusic):

```
public string Display
{
    get 
    {
        return this.TrackName;
    }
    set 
    {
        this.TrackName= value;
    }
}

public string Value
{
    get 
    {
        return this.TrackID;
    }
    set 
    {
        this.TrackID= value;
    }
}
```

And in your Artist class (also implements IMusic):

```
public string Display
{
    get 
    {
        return this.ArtistName;
    }
    set 
    {
        this.ArtistName= value;
    }
}

public string Value
{
    get 
    {
        return this.AritstID;
    }
    set 
    {
        this.AritstID= value;
    }
}
```